# best method for modeling a curved, diagonal rope pattern

Tags: bezier-curves

wondering what the best way would be to achieve the curved rope pattern seen on the back of this macrame chair: https://i.gyazo.com/48a19b01a2d7430d2f66ed964814e081.png

I've spent hours trying to figure out the best way to achieve a similar result. I've got the base of the chair down as it's a flat shape but the curved back is really throwing me for a loop. I've tried the tissue addon (to tessellate around a similar shape), I've tried a curve modifier, I've tried messing with array, and I even tried manually adjusting each individual rope, but I'm left frustrated and hoping someone might have a better method or suggestion!

here's what I've got so far: https://i.gyazo.com/d61f2366e000a05c30035f71d5bf3e24.png - very basic as I'm hoping to figure out these back ropes before adding additional details. any help is greatly appreciated! TIA.

Comment: this could be usefull https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+make+a+braid+in+blender+

Comment: thanks! i ended up modeling it by hand but these tutorials will definitely be useful in other areas.